# In Excel 2014, how to sum with certain patterns automatically?

Tags: excel, sum

I just made an awful formula in excel, which is:

=SUM(A1*C1, A2*C2, A3*C3 ... ... A21*C21)

I was forced to type the 21 elements one by one manually and still have no idea on how to solve the problem despite of long time Google searching...
Is there any elegant way that can solve such situation in more smart manner? ( maybe something like: =SMART_SUM(A1*C1 : A21*C21) )

thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical use case for `SUMPRODUCT`

`=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A21,C1:C21)`